# requestAuthorization result is invalid in applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: notifications, ios10

To get permission to show notifications, I request system and it returns the result ok, but meanwhile `applicationDidBecomeActive` is called and when I check for `UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()` it's 1 which is denied!

```
...
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) {(accepted, error) in
        if !accepted {
            print("Notification access denied.")
        }
    }
....

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {


    let grantedSettings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()
    let value= grantedSettings!.types.rawValue 
    // value is now 1, why?!
}
```